# Add a response from Jquery ajax to an already existing modal window

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, barcode

i have a little problem. I can't add response (barcode with title as div) that i get from jquery ajax.

js part

```
function generate_barcode(name) {
    $('#modal-barcode-profile').modal('show');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data/barcode_profile.php',
        method: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            code: name
        },
        success: function (response) {
            doSomething(response);
        },
    })
}

function doSomething(response) {

    $('#modal-barcode-profile').html(response);

}
```

html page

```
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($res as $r): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $r['name']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <center>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" onclick="fill_form('<?= $r['id'] ?>','<?= $r['name'] ?>');">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span> Edit</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="get_id('<?= $r['id'] ?>','del');">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> Delete</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" onclick="generate_barcode('<?= $r['name'] ?>')">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true"></span> Print</button>
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
 </tbody>
```

barcode_profile.php

```
<?php
  $generator = new Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorPNG();
  extract($_POST);
?>
<div id='test'>
<center><img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($generator->getBarcode($code, $generator::TYPE_CODE_128)) ?>"></center>
<div id="code"><center><?php echo $code ?></center></div>
</div>
```

and modal window

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-barcode-profile">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Barcode</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="print">Print Barcode</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">OK
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get response in browser when i click button to generate barcode, but div doesn't appear.
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try to add html on div with class "modal-content" instead of div with id "modal-barcode-profile"

Comment: After you have clicked to generate the barcode and the modal pops, if you inspect the modal, does it show your `<div id='test'>` in there?

Comment: @JCCavalca doesn't work too. I tried.

Comment: @Bossman In inspector browser doesn't show new element. That is the problem.

Comment: Just as a test, change `doSomething(response);` to this `doSomething('<div>testing</div>');` does that show in the modal?

Comment: @Bossman doesn't show in modal window.

Comment: Your AJAX success must not be triggering, try adding `console.log('ajax triggered')` in the AJAX success and see if that shows in the inspector..

Comment: I found problem. I changed in ajax datatype format from 'json' to 'html' and now it works.